# Add an Exclusive or featured tag line to article titles

Tags: categories

I want to display a big exclusive tag or image next to my articles headlines,when they are posted to in this case featured category.

An example of what im trying to achieve can be seen on tmz.com or buzzfeed.com

This is what i have tried so far.
I created a function in the function.php as below:

```
function new_badge(){
    if ( (time()-get_the_time('U')) <= (3*86400)) { 
        echo '<div class="new"></div>';
    }
}
```

the function basically looks at the time an article was published and if the article is not older than three days it calls the new class from the css.

In the style.css the class i made was as follows

```
.new {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('images/exclusive.png') no-repeat top left;
    z-index: 100
}
```

Then i called the class in the index.php

inside the post loop as follows:

```
<?php new_badge() ?>
```

My problem is that my function is still not working. what im i doimng wrong. my website is running wordpress 3.9

Ok from the Function you have provided me i tried ammending it to my loop and this is what i have:

```
<?php
global $loop_module_id, $loop_sidebar_position;

$td_template_layout = new td_template_layout($loop_sidebar_position);



if ($loop_module_id == 1 or $loop_module_id == 7 or $loop_module_id == 8 or      $loop_module_id == 9 or $loop_module_id == 'search') {
//disable the grid for mod 1 and 7 and search
$td_template_layout->disable_output();
}

if (have_posts()) {
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    echo $td_template_layout->layout_open_element(),new_badge();


    switch ($loop_module_id) {
        case '1':
            $td_mod = new td_module_1($post);
            break;
        case '2':
            $td_mod = new td_module_2($post);
            break;
        case '3':
            $td_mod = new td_module_3($post);
            break;
        case '4':
            $td_mod = new td_module_4($post);
            break;
        case '5':
            $td_mod = new td_module_5($post);
            break;
        case '6':
            $td_mod = new td_module_6($post);
            break;
        case '7':
            $td_mod = new td_module_7($post);
            break;
        case '8':
            $td_mod = new td_module_8($post);
            break;
        case '9':
            $td_mod = new td_module_9($post);
            break;
        case 'search':
            $td_mod = new td_module_search($post);
            break;
        default:
            $td_mod = new td_module_2($post);
            break;
    }
    echo $td_mod->render();


    echo $td_template_layout->layout_close_element();
    $td_template_layout->layout_next();
endwhile; //end loop
echo $td_template_layout->close_all_tags();


} else {
//no posts
echo td_page_generator::no_posts();
}
```

In my functions php i have written the function as below:

```
function new_badge($title){
global $post;
if ( has_category( 'ultrabooks', $post->ID ) ) { 
    $title  = '<div class="new">' . $title . '</div>';
}
return $title;
}
```

Comment: what isn't working? I think your problem might be with your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

[`get_the_time('U')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time#Return_Values) returns `$string`. You cannot subtract a **string** from an **integer**

```
function new_badge(){
    if ( (time() - strtotime ( get_the_time( 'U' ) ) ) <= (3*86400)) { 
        echo '<div class="new"></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem, as PHP has [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).